# Wpf/winforms create text boxes and labels from object

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, object

I'm often finding my self creating large objects with lots of properties for example customer data object including properties such as;
First name
Last name
Address 1
Address 2
Address 3

Etc which I will have to write an interface for using labels and text boxes for each property giving them both id's which can get a bit tedious after a while.

Is there any kid of macro or source code which would do such a thing for me? I've searched on Google but I don't think I quite get the search for as I'm not entirely sure what I'm searching for.

Comment: You could always override `TextBox` with `CustomerTextBox`? I don't quite understand your question

Comment: Did you concider creating Customcontrols with XAML style with contains all this staff binded to your ViewModel? It is much easier to write XAML then instantiating all controls in code behind

Comment: Sorry maybe didn't explain brilliantly, the object isn't always customer data it could be a sales order object or a invoice object etc but every time I then have to create an array of labels and text boxes so I can create inputs for this data

Comment: Are you asking for an answer in Winforms or WPF? Because if I understand your question correctly, this would be very different. In WPF, you'd simply create an implicit `DataTemplate` for your object, and WPF would use this template anytime it needs to draw your object. For WinForms, you'd probably have to do what you're doing now which is creating Labels and TextBoxes, giving them Ids, and assigning the Text properties manually from code behind. I've had some luck recording macros using VS Macros, but I'm not sure if I understand what you're doing enough to help you with that.

Comment: You know you can just drag and drop from the Data Sources window - is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you wanted some way to generate the controls dynamically, try something like this

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateControls();
    }

    private void CreateControls()
    {
        var c = new Customer("SomeFirstName", "SomeLastName", "Something");
        PropertyInfo[] pi = c.GetType().GetProperties();
        Label lbl;
        TextBox tb;
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        foreach (var p in pi)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(p.Name);
            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Content = p.Name;

            tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Text = p.GetValue(c, null).ToString();

            sp.Children.Add(lbl);
            sp.Children.Add(tb);
        }
       //Replace MainGrid with any control you want these to be added.
        MainGrid.Children.Add(sp);
    }


}

public class Customer
{
    public Customer(string first, string last, string title)
    {
        FirstName = first;
        LastName = last;
        Title = title;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This solution does not conform to any of the WPF best practices and guidelines. If anything, you should be creating Bindings between the Data item and the UI elements, so that updating the values in the UI would actually update the values in the underlying data object.